# Поздравление с приростом подписчиков

Tags: грамотная-речь, жаргон

У друга пошел прирост подписчиков на странице, я хочу его поздравить с этим событием на молодёжном сленге. Правильно ли я написал?

*Нихрена себе у тебя  прирост подписчиков пошел. Поздравляю, друг мой. Лучший.

Нихрена себе у тебя подписчики пошли. Поздравляю, друг мой. Лучший.*

Comment: http://gramota.ru/slovari/argo/53_8214

Comment: Вы слишком начитаны, и налицо диссонанс. Если переводить на школярский, то каждое слово. И ошибок побольше.

Comment: @shampar Да тут вообще нет сленга. "Ни хрена себе!" даже есть в словаре Кузнецова, это не сленг.

Comment: Можно ли так написать? Есть ли ошибки?

Comment: Есть сленг, нет его, неважно. Стиля нет, в этом и ошибка.

Comment: Отличное разговорное предложение (первое). Второе слишком двусмысленное, в разговоре сойдет, но на странице лучше использовать первое. Нихрена я бы писал вместе как ничего.

Comment: @user190920 Оно отличное только в том плане, что поймут.

Answer (score 1):

"Ни хрена" — везде фиксируется раздельное написание.

*Ничего себе / ни хрена себе* обычно используется перед существительным (без глагола), использование перед простым предложением здесь не совсем верно (глагол лучше убрать). Да, и так поймут, но интересует же, как правильно. Если оно и используется в предложении с глаголом, то тогда, когда важен глагол, а не подлежащее (например: *Ни хрена себе они намусорили!*), а здесь наоборот (и поэтому звучит не идеально).

Выражение "ни хрена" передаёт удивление, так что желателен восклицательный знак.

Более грамотный вариант:
*Ни хрена себе, какой у тебя прирост подписчиков! Поздравляю, друг мой — лучший!*
"Лучший" не очень звучит, если сильно отделить (точкой). А так это уточнение, но с интонационным тире, которое соответствует данному слову.